# iOS: Enterprise build with over the air install support using Fastlane

Tags: ios, ipa, enterprise, fastlane, ota

I am trying to configure my Fastfile to get an enterprise build with over the air installation support. Here is my current lane:

```
lane :enterprise do
  increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "myapp.xcodeproj")
  build_app(
      scheme: "enterprise",
      output_name: "myapp.ipa",
      output_directory: "build",
      export_options: {
        manifest: {
          appURL: "my app url",
          displayImageURL: "display image url",
          fullSizeImageURL: "full size image url"
        }
      },
      export_method: "enterprise",
      export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates"
   )
end
```

The build runs withouth problem and I get both `ipa` and `manifest.plist` ffiles. The problem is when get the build with Xcode, it produces 5 files:

- DistributionSummary.plist
- ExportOptions.plist
- manifest.plist
- Packaging.log
- myapp.ipa

When I try to update the files by just changing ipa and the plist files, over the air intallation failes wih this error:

```
Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13
"Failed to verify code signature of /.../myapp.app : 0xe8008017 
(A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.)"
UserInfo={
  NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of /.../myapp.app : 0xe8008017 
  (A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted.),
  LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed,
  FunctionName=+[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:],
  SourceFileLine=77,
  LibMISErrorNumber=-402620393
}
for bundle IDs ("com.myapp")
```

How can I make Fastlane generate all these files?

**UPDATE**

I have managed to get `DistributionSummary.plist` and `ExportOptions.plist`using below code:

```
fastlane_require "gym"
dist_plist_path = File.join(Gym.cache[:temporary_output_path], "DistributionSummary.plist")
FileUtils.cp(dist_plist_path, "../build")
dist_plist_path = File.join(Gym.cache[:temporary_output_path], "ExportOptions.plist")
FileUtils.cp(dist_plist_path, "../build")
```

But I am still getting error when I try to install the app.

**UODATE 2**

I have tried deleting all the files except `ipa` and `manifest` with Xcode export and It is still working except it doesn't show app icon while downloading the app. So the error I am getting isn't related to other files.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. My app name contains a non `ASCII` character **"ö"** and it cousing the problem when I try to get an enterprise export. I gess enterprise package validation doesn't handle non ASCII characters. After changing the character the problem is solved.